# How to transfer local files using PuTTY via ssh to remote server?

Tags: putty

I have installed puTTY for Windows 10 and access a remote server via SSH. I want to send the files from my local Windows box to the remote server. How can I do this?

I am using puTTY but psftp, pscp etc. are also an option.

I use this.

`pscp.exe i F:\.ssh\anotherprivate.ppk "F:\xss vulnerability.txt" utkarsh@52.42.74.119.`

And got this:

```
More than one remote source not supported
```

Comment: You seem to have an un-necessary trailing dot. Is that real or a typo? Also, what's that lone `i` doing immediately after the `pscp.exe` command? If it's a typo please ensure that what you show us here accurately reflects what you're trying on your own system

Comment: Is it really a duplicat? In the mentioned question and answer (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92716/223965) there isn't explained how to connect with a private key. So IMO this question has a right to exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have two errors:

First typo, you should use `-i F:\.ssh\anotherprivate.ppk` (notice the hyphen).

Second you could specify the folder on the target system (or end with colon for the user's home folder): `utkarsh@52.42.74.119:/tmp/`

That leads to the whole command:

```
pscp.exe -i F:\.ssh\anotherprivate.ppk "F:\xss vulnerability.txt" utkarsh@52.42.74.119:/tmp/
```

Comment: You don't need to specify a target folder on the remote system. If you omit that it will default to your home directory there.

Comment: ok thanks, I didn't know that, I always specify it. And on my machine it does not work without colon at the and of the remote target. then probably the dot at the end of the original posts command.

Comment: The colon is required. A remote path is optional.

Answer (score 1):

Use [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php) (Windows 10 compatible) to download/upload files to remote server:

[image]

Also you can use putty as part of WinSCP:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you should add a screenshot of the menu in advanced where you could set the private key. Because the original post is using a ssh key to connect.